# Search pagination uses lowercase

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

The pagination links on a search results page (and possibly elsewhere, I haven't tested) do lowercase the current URL. That is, when I search for

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CONSTRUCTOR

the <kbd>next</kbd> link at the bottom becomes

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=constructor

*Usually*, that doesn't matter, as search is case-insensitive. Well, not always: when I am searching for link usage via `url:"…"`, it's pretty important. And [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A"https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects") yields over 23000 results, while [page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=url%3a"https%3a%2f%2fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2fen-us%2fdocs%2fweb%2fjavascript%2freference%2fglobal_objects") is suddenly empty. Oops.

Comment: As a workaround you can copy query part for url from initial search, and use for other pages, or manually change page number in query...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're going to preserve the query case in the page links starting with the next build.

Thanks for the report!